# Can I play audio/video of salah-in-masjid and virtually/remotely offer congregational prayer while staying at home (if I am unable to leave home)?

Tags: quran, hadith, salat, masjid, jamaat

I live in a place where no women have the option of going to masjid. We pray at home. Moreover, I have some physical limitation and I can not go anywhere right now. I don't think I have anyone who I could ask to do congregational prayer with me inside the home.

We are still left with 23rd, 25th, 27th and 29th nights of Ramadan. I really want to offer isha and fajr in congregation.

1. Can I pray in congregation while playing a audio/video of congregational prayer in some masjid in the world?
2. Would you know any such video on YouTube may be, which I can play and then offer my salah along in order to be a part of the congregation?

Comment: You can not join a congregation via video\audio, see [this](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/50245/) and [this](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/45611) etc. Also please note that for a woman prayer at home is more virtuous than praying at the mosque see [here](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/8868/).

Comment: It is even doubtful whether your prayer is valid if you prayed outside the mosque. How would your prayer be valid if you neither see the imam and are in the same location (which is a condition from the perspective of some scholars) nor pray on the same time since generally youtube videos wouldn't be live streams... You can perform taraweeh by yourself it isn't a mandtory prayer and therefore praying it alone is perfectly fine, you can either recite from what you have memorized or recite from a moshaf.